# Spotfire IronPython Skip filters from certain table

Tags: filter, ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I am using Spotfire 7.10.

I have a script, that updates a document property containing the active filters. To do so, I loop over the filters matching the "status:m" search like so:

```
filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "status:m"
for filter in filterPanel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
    filteroutput = filter.FilterReference.ToString()
    content += filteroutput + "\n"
```

I would like to skip over filters coming from Table1, whilst filters in Table2 are supposed to be displayed.

Any idea on how to skip over them? Both tables have fields with overlapping names, e.g. "Color", so i can't go by the name but need a reference to the originating data table.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ParentGroup to determine which table the filter belongs to and then skip the ones you dont need

```
import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.PanelCollection

import Spotfire.Dxp.Application.PanelTypeIdentifiers
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import Panel
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Layout import PanelState as ps
for panel in Document.ActivePageReference.Panels:
 if panel.TypeId.DisplayName == "Filters":
  panel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "status:m"
  for filter in panel.FiltersMatchingSearchPattern:
   filteroutput = filter.FilterReference.ToString()
   print "Table-" + str(filter.Context.ParentGroup.Name) + "---Filter - " +str(filteroutput)
```